# OSM+Leaflet tiles not loading or showing up (Android-Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, leaflet, openstreetmap

I made a cordova app a couple of months ago which uses openstreetmap and leaflet.js. It was working fine and it still works on Android phones that my team mates uses everyday BUT when I try to use it on some new tablets (with Android 10) my app only loads (or only shows) gray map tiles.

Other functions like retrieving coordinates, markers and others seems to be working well but the map tiles are not loading or showing up.

How can I solve this?

My config to load the map in a div with id="mapa" is:

```
var caracteristicas_mapa = {
   center: [0, 0],
   zoom: 17
}

// Crear objeto mapa
window.mapa = new L.map('mapa', caracteristicas_mapa);

// Crear objeto capa (layer)
var capa = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'); 

// Agregando la capa al mapa
window.mapa.addLayer(capa);
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Use https for the TileLayer URL.

(You should get a redirect from http to https, but loading mixed content may be blocked by your application).